# Extend Network by Connecting a Wireless Router to a Wired Router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1794/using-a-wireless-router-as-a-home-network-switch) question and it seems similar, however I dont have an XBOX and its not D-Link specific as both of my network devices are D-Link.  So, I figured I'd ask.

I just purchased a D-Link DIR-825 wireless router and I am hoping that I can "extend" my LAN by connecting it to my existing D-Link DGL-4100 wired router.

I dont know if I worded that correctly but basically, I'd like to be able to connect an Ethernet cable from one of the ports on the 4100 (wired) to one of the ports on the 825 (wireless and wired) and gain 3 extra wired ports as well as serve wireless in my house.

Currently, the 4100 is set up as 192.168.1.1 and is the DHCP server for the network.  There will be two iPhones, a laptop and an iMac connecting to the wireless and three other desktops plus a printer on the wired.

If the answers for my situation are the same then I shall delete this question and refer there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. go to the wireless router setup and turn off its dhcp server and set up a fixed ip address to it.
2. connect the wired router and the wireless router - lan connection to lan connection (as odd as it sounds)
3. check if you can access the wireless router from a box connected to the wired router
4. if so test the wired connection, then the wireless.

This worked in a similar setup for me.

Comment: Do this, not what the other answer says to do.

Comment: What happened to the other answer???????????   From "Molly" I think it was?   I could have sworn it was here last night and I began to have problems with the setup wizard and had to call it quits.  Oh well, I will try your suggestion and will post back what I find out..  Thanks!

Comment: still having problems getting the install/setup program to run on vista 64.  I will get back here eventually!  I have to call D-Link...

Comment: you don't need the install disk. You just need to use the web setup

Comment: Eventually, that is where I went.  What I *think* happened was my PC was not actually connected to the 825.  It was connected to the 4100 and there was no way I was going to ever connect to the 825 unless I disconnected from the 4100 for the time being in order to set up the 825.  I now have the 4100 as my "primary" gateway/link to the Internet with the 825 with a fixed address.  I suppose I could reverse that if I wanted to.  I dont know which way would be faster/better, and I will test it all out.  Thank you!

Comment: Many routers also have options to transform into an access point, which eliminates the need to manually disable router settings. Another more advanced setup is to give the second dlink the exact same settings (SSID, WPA passphrase) etc so wireless clients can roam without having to connect to another network. Otherwise you'll need to recconect to whatever network is stronger based on location.