# One computer not connecting

Tags: windows-7, networking, shared-access

so here is the scope and story of my issue. I am currently in a hotel that has LAN access in its rooms. I have two computers that I am attempting to connect the their network. Seeing as there is only one port on the wall I have my Five port dumb switch with me. My first computer is having no issues connecting even through the switch "tried all 5 ports" however the second computer is not connecting.

Troubleshooting completed.

- Ran network scan and found there are many unused available addresses.
- Ran Virtual machine with masked MAC of second computer within the first computer. "No issues"
- Connected second computer first and primary second and issue is caused to opposite computer.
- Ipconfig on Second computer shows APIPA
- Requested front desk restart their router. No luck there
- Ran DoS attack on front desk router to cause restart no change.

If anyone could please shoot me some more Ideas I would appreciate it.

Comment: by "dumb switch" do you mean hub? Or is it really a switch?

Comment: It is just a 5 port Ethernet switch with no advanced functionality and no configuration abilities.

Comment: 1 IP Address per room. 2 computers = 2 IP addresses, even with a dumb switch.

Comment: Please read trouble shooting steps taken:
Ran Virtual machine with masked MAC of second computer within the first computer. "No issues" the VM has a different IP than first computer.

Comment: is the VM bridged or nat-ted?

Comment: The VM is connecting via NAT as a stand alone no bridge enabled. More specifically VM Bridge is disabled.

Comment: If the VM is connecting via a soft-nat, then all the VM's traffic would look like it is coming from the host machine.  I have to agree with @ekaj that it sounds like you're being limited to 1 IP for the room.  If either machine has 2 ethernet ports, you could loop the hotel line into one, then do internet connection sharing to the other via the switch.

Comment: Did you check the speed/duplex setting on the NIC? It will probably need to be auto to connect to a hub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They obviously are only providing ONE IP address to each LAN connection.

Find a way to insert NAT-type routing (such has a small router or internet-sharing).

Answer (score 4):

If i were to make a guess, you just arn't getting an ip address - i suspect one solution would be to set your switch to a fixed ip address in the range they have, and turn off the DHCP server on it and plug it into the network through a *regular* non 'internet port' - this approach works well when daisy chaining routers. See [instructions](https://superuser.com/a/116293/10165) here.

Edit:

Ahh, more details - if you're running a VM on nat mode, you're running a small additional network inside your system - this in no way simulates an actual second system with its own ip address.

Iornix is right about there very likely only being a single ip address provided by the hotel, and his suggested solutions seem to make sense to me. Peter Maxwell's comment about using connectify may be an option, or you could play around with setting up a softap or ad hoc network between the systems.

Comment: Recap on what I just said above, It is a 5 port Ethernet switch with no advanced functionality and no configuration abilities.

Comment: You're sure it isn't a hub?

Comment: A hub might actually work here with no issues.

Comment: a switch is just an intelligent hub, and it won't do NAT or magically create an IP address for you.

Comment: no, but a hub lacks the parts of a switch which i see giving trouble when 'just' tacking on another couple of systems into an existing network. Most 'switches', least at the consumer level (people don't travel with a rackmount do they?) are really routers as well. A hub just transmits everything to everyone. Switches do *some* intelligent stuff. Routers do more. I didn't have the information that was added when i made that comment - the answer does take that and your answer (and others!) into account.

Answer (score 3):

If you have laptops (or PCs with wireless cards), you could connect one to LAN, create a wireless network and connect the other laptop to it.  Since they would be located close to each other, you would have a minimal speed drop.

In the meantime, keep up the DoS attacks on the hotel for not giving you more ports! XD

Comment: Sorry, not really a solution but a workaround.  Better than nothing though.

Comment: Desktops and its a corporate stay place with no WiFi only LAN.

Comment: Sorry then (I meant connect to LAN not WiFi.)

Comment: Just connect your computers and bridge a network.

Comment: You could just use something like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/).

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but why not add a second IP to the Nic on the working desktop and use intenet sharing via that IP?

That would look something like this:

Before:

```
                   (5 port Switch)
                   |  |  |   |  |
Hotel plug --------/  |
                      |
                   Desktop1
   With hotel given DHCP IP
```

After

```
                    5 port Switch)
                   |  |  |   |  |
Hotel plug --------/  |          Desktop2
                      |
                   Desktop1
   With hotel given DHCP IP & a second IP manually configured
   via 'network connections' screen
        select the NIC, open properties
        select 'internet protocol version 4'. Properties
        [Advanced]
        Add a IP outside the hotel range.
        Then enable internet sharing via this new IP.
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the time that it took for me to get back on this.

Unknown to the front desk they had a commercial distribution point so each room had an independent connection over Ethernet.

Resolution was to add a router into the mix.
Until I asked to take a look at their equipment I was afraid to do this in fear of causing issues to everyone else.

Thank you for everyone's assistance.