# Expanding Wired Network with Wireless Router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet, home-networking

I want to expand my home network with the ASUS RT-N66U. I want several workstations in one part of the house to be wired, but the other workstations in another part of the house to be wireless, while at the same time, being able to access all the machines (e.g. printer) in the network via LAN.

Obviously, connecting the LAN side of the main switch to the WAN socket of the wireless router doesn't do anything because this means that I won't be able to access anything that isn't connected to the wireless router.

I've followed the instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/104043/extend-network-by-connecting-a-wireless-router-to-a-wired-router), but after doing so, I get an error message saying that the router isn't connected to WAN whenever I try to access something on the internet.

To sum up everything, here is my setup:
ASUS RT-N66U connected to a switch's LAN port via the ASUS router's WAN slot. The switch is connected to the modem

And here is my problem: Although I can use the internet, I am having trouble connecting to a printer that is wired up to the switch. How can I make it so that I can connect to the internet and access all other machines in my home network.

Comment: Have you tried setting the router to AP mode? Those instructions were really meant for older routers, and asuses seem quite different from the WRT54GL and random ISP supplied routers I used then

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty straightforward to me. Use the ASUS RT-N66U as the main router (default configuration) for your network by connecting its WAN port to your internet connection (I suppose Cable or DSL modem but was not specified). Then connect all of your switches to any of the RT-N66U LAN ports. If your switches don't have auto-detect ports you need to use the uplink port or a crossover cable. This configuration will create a single LAN composed of all your wired and wireless devices.

Here I assumed that you already had something like a wired router for all your devices and that you don't mind replacing it by the ASUS RT-N66U but it was not specified in your question.

Comment: I hadn't read the link you posted in your question but if seems you may want to keep both routers and use the ASUS RT-N66U as an Access Point only. Unless the RT-N66U as an "AP only" mode I would not recommend using both routers at the same time. I tried something similar already with 2 Linksys routers and even after disabling DHCP on the wireless one it was still causing some issues.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the setup in our house, that is not going to work for us. Joruneyman Greek suggested that I switch it to AP mode. I did that and tried connected the LAN and WAN port of the wireless access point to the switch, I get no internet access. How am I supposed to set up the access point properly?

Comment: My switch is connected to the modem, which is in turn, connected to the internet. Here is a summary of my situation - Router set to AP mode and connected to the main switch via WAN or LAN: cannot connect to anything. Router set to router mode and connected to the main switch via LAN: cannot connect to anything. Router set to router mode and connected to the main switch via WAN: can only connect to the internet.

Comment: Set it to AP mode and then connect it to your main switch through a LAN port. However after you have done that you need to restart all your devices that connect to your wifi because they need to get the new network configuration through DHCP.

Comment: I just tried that again, but to no avail. It still says "No internet access" even though I am connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but was an issue for me just recently. The way I got around it was that the ASUS router needs to be in Wireless router mode.

Connect the ASUS router's WAN port direct to your cable/fibre modem that was supplied. Do not connect this side to the switch as this will cause routing problems.

If like me the router is far away from your modem try using home plugs this will extend it's reach. I use Devolo and they seem to be very good.

Then once connected and you have an established internet connection connect one of the LAN ports to your switch. And hey presto. Should all be working. Took me a long while to figure that out! Hope this helps someone.